# How to detect and extract the position of text from images in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, tesseract, text-recognition

How to detect and extract the position of text from images. For ex the text "pepsi" from pepsi bottle image.
http://www.csmonitor.com/var/ezflow_site/storage/images/media/content/2013/0321-new-pepsi-bottle.jpg/15343519-1-eng-US/0321-new-pepsi-bottle.jpg_full_600.jpg

Answer (score 1):

At first you need a two pictures like this. Use a canny in opencv or photoshop.

[image]
[image]

Then make the background differencing as following

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat model = Highgui.imread("D:\\BKDiff\\can1.jpg",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat scene = Highgui.imread("D:\\BKDiff\\can2.jpg",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat diff = new Mat();
    Core.absdiff(model,scene,diff);
    Imgproc.threshold(diff,diff,15,1000,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    int distortion = Core.countNonZero(diff);
    Highgui.imwrite("D:\\BKDiff\\out.jpg",diff);
```

After that, you will get this.

[image]

Comment: yeah thanks its working fine, now i need to draw a rectangular box on this logo we got, how can i do this..

Comment: i am using the below code to find bounding box
    cv::Mat threshold_output;
    cv::Mat m = img.clone();
    cv::blur(m, m, cv::Size(5,5));
    std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    cv::findContours(m, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    m.release();
    for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++) {
            cv::Point p = contours[i][j];
            points.push_back(p);
        }
    }
    return cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(points).reshape(2));

Comment: You can use submat to retrive the text.

Comment: I tried using opencv, but unable to retrive text and its position from image. Anyway thanks zawhtut.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the following paper on [Stroke Width transform](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf). Its simple to implement and gives quite high accuracy.

I see there is an [implementation](http://libccv.org/doc/doc-swt/) also.